# How to show tabs AFTER user has logged in (separate navigators)

Tags: react-native, expo, react-navigation

I want a user to log in BEFORE they are taken to the "Home" screen. Once they hit the home screen, the tabs are shown. I do not want to show the tabs during login/signup.

Here is what I have so far:

```
const Stack = createStackNavigator();
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();
const Switch = createSwitchNavigator();
const AppContainer = createAppContainer();


function AuthNavigation() {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator headerMode="none" initialRouteName="Login">
        <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={Login} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Signup" component={Signup} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  )
}

function MyTabs() {

return (

<Tab.Navigator
initialRouteName="Home"
activeColor="#161F3D"
inactiveColor="#B8BBC4">

<Tab.Screen 
  name="Home" 
  component={Home} 
  // options={{
  //   tabBarIcon: <Icon name="home" size={24} />
  // }}
/>

<Tab.Screen 
  name="Leaderboard" 
  component={Leaderboard} 
  // options={{
  //   tabBarIcon: <Icon name="trophy" size={24} />
  // }}
/>

<Tab.Screen 
  name="Create" 
  component={Create} 
  // options={{
  //   tabBarIcon: <Icon name="add" size={40} />
  // }}
/>

<Tab.Screen 
  name="Notifications" 
  component={Notification} 
  // options={{
  //   tabBarIcon: <Icon name="notifications-circle-outline" size={24} />
  // }}
/>

<Tab.Screen 
  name="Profile"
  component={Profile}
  // options={{
  //   tabBarIcon: <Icon name="person" size={24} />
  // }} 
/>

  </Tab.Navigator>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <AppContainer>
      <Switch.Navigator headerMode="none" initialRouteName="Auth">
        <Switch.Screen name="Auth" component={AuthNavigation()} />
        <Switch.Screen name="Tabs" component={MyTabs()} />
    </Switch.Navigator>
    </AppContainer>
  );
}
```

This results in the following error:

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'Object.keys(routeConfigs)')
```

How can I build these two navigators so the auth and the tab navigators are separate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need to pass the reference of the component. You don't need to execute it. It should look like this -

```
<Switch.Screen name="Auth" component={AuthNavigation} />
<Switch.Screen name="Tabs" component={MyTabs} />
```

Comment: I am still getting the same error^. I also tried changing the switch to a stack and it didn't work.